# Spark stand-alone v 2.3.2 Failing test

Tags: apache-spark-sql, spark-hive, sparkcore, spark-repl

I have build spark v 2.3.2 on big endian platform using adopt jdk 1.8
build is successful and we encounter test case failures in the following module.
I wanted some information related to this failing test, information on how severely would this failures effect spark functionality

Test Module                     Severity (1. Must Fix, 2. Not Must Fix)

core

unsafe

Spark Project SQL

Spark Project Hive

Spark Project Repl

We would be glad if u can address our question by associating above shown severity numbers to respective failing test module